# How to register beans in beanfactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to have multiple JobDetailFactoryBean, CronTriggerFactoryBean and SchedulerFactoryBean. How can I register this beans to the beanfactory ? I am using spring boot.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("uk.co.themoderngeek.quartz.speakingclock")
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${quartz.db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${quartz.db.password}")
    private String password;

    public QuartzConfiguration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        JobDetailFactoryBean j1 = jobDetailFactoryBeanCreator("group1","job1");
        CronTriggerFactoryBean c1 = cronTriggerFactoryBeanCreator(j1, "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *");
        SchedulerFactoryBean s1 = schedulerFactoryBeanCreator(c1);

        JobDetailFactoryBean j2 = jobDetailFactoryBeanCreator("group2","job2");
        CronTriggerFactoryBean c2 = cronTriggerFactoryBeanCreator(j2, "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *");
        SchedulerFactoryBean s2 = schedulerFactoryBeanCreator(c2);

        JobDetailFactoryBean j3 = jobDetailFactoryBeanCreator("group3","job3");
        CronTriggerFactoryBean c3 = cronTriggerFactoryBeanCreator(j3, "0 0/2 * 1/1 * ? *");
        SchedulerFactoryBean s3 = schedulerFactoryBeanCreator(c3);
    }

   @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBeanCreator(String group, String name){
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(SpeakingClockJob.class);
        factory.setGroup(group);
        factory.setName(name);
        return factory;
    }

   @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBeanCreator(JobDetailFactoryBean bean, String cron){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(bean.getObject());
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setCronExpression(cron);
        return stFactory;
    }

   @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBeanCreator(CronTriggerFactoryBean ct) {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(ct.getObject());
        scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        scheduler.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return scheduler;
    }


    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource data = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        data.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        data.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz");
        data.setUsername("name");
        data.setPassword("password");
        return data;
    }
```

when I am running the above code I am getting this error. how can I create `JobDetailFactoryBean`, `CronTriggerFactoryBean` and `SchedulerFactoryBean` dynamically because when I have to add any job I have to create these beans to execute the job so I want to create it dynamically.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class`

Comment: can you add the code of one of your factory beans ?

Comment: @reos - that's what I am looking for how can I add or register methods in the beanfactory so that they can be considered as beans ?

Comment: I think your error is because you don't have defined a bean like     @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

Comment: I have check that out without using `@Autowired private BeanFactory beanFactory`; still getting same error. My actual problem is If I have to run any job I have create beans `JobDetailFactoryBean` and `CronTriggerFactoryBean` I want to create these beans dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood what you ask, but you can declare all the beans you want with different attributes, just changing the method name.
For example:

```
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBeanOne(){
    JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobClass(SpeakingClockJob.class);
    factory.setGroup("group1");
    factory.setName("job1");
    return factory;
}
```

Then you have to use @Autowired like this:

```
@Autowired
private JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBeanOne;
```

or

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("jobDetailFactoryBeanOne")
private JobDetailFactoryBean nameWhatYouWant;
```

Comment: this what I am trying to do [link](http://pastebin.com/YXniYeUF) I am trying to register beans into the beanfactory.

Answer (score 0):

When you use @Bean your method have not to have arguments. In case you need arguments they need to be Spring beans.

So you can define your bean as prototype. When a bean has prototype scope Spring return a new instance of that bean every time a class refers to it.

After getting your bean you can set the parameter that the bean needs through bean properties.

Here there are two tutorials that will help you.

https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html